# DOM Manipulation - append a string-variable with dom content

Tags: javascript, dom

haven't found a solution for my problem. I have to admit that i had problems to find the correct search terms. It seems i don't see the forest for the trees - once again...

I'm trying to append a child element, which isn't spectacular at all. But now i have a variable (ajax - json) which already contains a dom element (<a href="xx"><img src="xx" /></a>) and i wan't to add this content.

First approach `elem.appendChild(var);`

throws this error: *NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8*

Next try `elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(var));` encodes the entities. So the anchor and img-tag are printed plain.

any help? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to using `appendChild` with a textural representation of elements, not a dom node itself. Try using the `innerHTML` property:

```
elem.innerHTML += "<a href=\"xx\"><img src=\"xx\" /></a>";
```

JQuery has a nice `append` method which takes care of all this for you:

```
$("div.someDiv").append("<a href=\"xx\"><img src=\"xx\" /></a>");
```

Comment: thanks. Yeah, jQuery is cool and helps a lot. Unfortunately the code is for a js snippet, which should be integrated into other websites. So i should keep everything small and mustn't include some extra librarys.